# Specifying oCPM Bid Geared for Actions (Offsite Conversions)

Tags: facebook, optimization, action, ads, bids

My question is regarding how to combine a campaign set for Optimized-CPM bidding and the conversion spec for an off-site pixel conversion to delivery impressions focused on generating more off-site conversions.

My secondary question is how to correctly set the maximum CPM cost for receiving impressions specifcally geared towards those actions.

I have gone back and forth with facebook, developers, co-workers and spent hours researching this issue online.  According to the facebook developers guides, it appears like it is possible to use the API to process the requests above in a fairly simple manner.  However, I am trying to figure out how to go about setting these values using either the Facebook Ads interface or the Power Editor.  The issue I am experiencing is that even after I have set an advertisement to the oCPM setting and even after I have requested it to track and focus on generating off-site conversions I cannot edit the field for specifying the impression cost.  Regardless of what I do on my end in the power editor, the action box remains grey and cannot be edited.

Can anyone let me know if they have experience with this issue and may have a solution?

### Thanks,